# How to do typed CWebUser objects in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I'd like to be able to have `Guest` and `User` classes that both extend `CWebUser`.  Is it possible for the application somewhere to determine which class to load based on whether the user is logged in or not?

My objective is for `Yii::app()->user->getMyStuff()` to do different things based on whether the user is a guest or logged in user.  I can't see any obvious ways to make this happen.

I could always do...

```
function getMyStuff() {
   if ($this->isGuest){
       .....
   } else {
       .....
   }
}
```

But I don't want to overload a single class with all of that...

Comment: is guest also a authenticated user?

Comment: No, it's a non-authenticated user